# How to get a DataGrid column name when the header is clicked, WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, mouseevent

I am trying to determine the column name of a clicked column using the following event handler.

Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name ="LoggedGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-3,288,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="198" Width="973">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="columnHeader_Click" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

And here is the event handler, I cannot figure out how to determine the column name after the column has been clicked, any ideas?

```
private void columnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not cast the sender as DataGridColumnHeader and then gets its Content like this.

```
private void columnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string header = ((DataGridColumnHeader)sender).Content.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please add a code sample to show the OP what you describe.  Also, did you mean 'cast' instead of 'case'?